# Physical significance of iterating spherical bessel functions with itself

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

When solving the Schrodinger equation for a nucleus, e.g. infinite spherical well problem, the eigenfunctions are of the form $\Psi(r,θ,ϕ)=R(r)Y_{l,m}(θ,ϕ)$, where the $Y_{l,m}$'s are the usual spherical harmonics. From this, it can be shown that the radial equation solutions involve the spherical Bessel equations (These special functions obviously arise in other problems such as the Helmholtz equations for example, but here we can restrict ourselves to discussing the above mentioned problem). The general spherical Bessel function can be written, using Rayleigh's formula, as:
$$j_n(x)=(-x)^n\left(\frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{dx}\right)^n \frac{\sin x}{x}$$
We can restrict ourselves here to discussing the above Bessel function of the first kind, and not linger on the others. Now, if we were to take $j_n(j_n(x))=(-j_n(x))^n\left(\frac{1}{j_n(x)} \frac{d}{dx}\right)^n \frac{\sin ( j_n(x))}{j_n(x)}$, does this particular function composition describe any sort of physical situation or interaction involving the nucleus?

Comment: This is implicit to my question. Does restricting the independent variable of a Bessel function to be a Bessel function represent a particular physical situation and/or what is its physical interpretation?

Comment: No, and you have serious domain problems, what with starting from the positive half line and flying off in the [first iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function). These functions do not have simple nesting properties, in case you were inspired by that of the celebrated  *nesting property of Chebyshev polynomials*,   $T_m(T_n(x)) = T_{m n} (x)$, by the functional conjugacy property,  $T_n(x)=  \cos(n \arccos (x))$.

Comment: Yes, the Chebyshev polynomials certainly inspired this question. But further, more as a mathematical exercise, I was curious to see if an n-fold iteration of the general Bessel Function of the first and second kind ($J_{\alpha}(x), \ Y_{\alpha}(x)$), would lead to nice closed form expressions, if these yielded any interesting results and if they have any relevance to physics at all. But as you mentioned there are certainly issues in regards to the topology domain for an iterative spherical Bessel function.

Comment: The Rayleigh formula is far-far from a conjugacy relation of any kind....

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I must admit, I am not very well versed in group theory. If you have any recommended readings that may clarify the link between conjugacy relations and iterated functions, I would gladly dive into those.

Comment: [Here is a start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Conjugacy), but also [Schroeder's astounding equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schröder%27s_equation#Applications) which provides the arbitrary iteration trajectory of a function, even for noninteger (even fractional) iteration.  Recall matrix conjugacy in linear systems, when you take an *n* th power of a matrix you diagonalize.